# Strange Stack Overflow Error in Sudoko Backtracker

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, sudoku, backtracking

(Disclaimer: There are maybe 20 different versions of this question on SO, but a reading through most of them still hasn't solved my issue)

Hello all, (relatively) beginner programmer here. So I've been trying to build a Sudoku backtracker that will fill in an incomplete puzzle. It seems to works perfectly well even when 1-3 rows are completely empty (i.e. filled in with 0's), but when more boxes start emptying (specifically around the 7-8 column in the fourth row, where I stopped writing in numbers) I get a Stack Overflow Error. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Sudoku
{
    public static int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];
    public static int filledIn = 0;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> blankBoxes = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    public static int currentIndex = 0;
    public static int runs = 0;

    /**
     * Main method.
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        //Manual input of the numbers
        int[] completedNumbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,
                8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
                3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,
                6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,
                9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};


        //Adds the numbers manually to the puzzle array
        ArrayList<Integer> completeArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer number : completedNumbers) {
            completeArray.add(number);
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                puzzle[i][j] = completeArray.get(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        //Adds all the blank boxes to an ArrayList.
        //The index is stored as 10*i + j, which can be retrieved
        // via modulo and integer division.
        boolean containsEmpty = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if(puzzle[i][j] == 0) {
                    blankBoxes.add(10*i + j);
                    containsEmpty = true;
                }
            }
        }
        filler(blankBoxes.get(currentIndex));
    }

    /**
     * A general method for testing whether an array contains a
     * duplicate, via a (relatively inefficient) sort.
     * @param testArray The int[] that is being tested for duplicates
     * @return True if there are NO duplicate, false if there
     * are ANY duplicates.
     */

    public static boolean checkDupl(int[] testArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int num = testArray[i];
            for(int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
                if(num == testArray[j] && num != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * If the puzzle is not full, the filler will be run. The filler is my attempt at a backtracker.
     * It stores every (i,j) for which puzzle[i][j] == 0. It then adds 1 to it's value. If the value
     * is already somewhere else, it adds another 1. If it is 9, and that's already there, it loops to 
     * 0, and the index beforehand is rechecked.
     */
    public static void filler(int indexOfBlank) {
        //If the current index is equal to the size of blankBoxes, meaning that we
        //went through every index of blankBoxes, meaning the puzzle is full and correct.
        runs++;
        if(currentIndex == blankBoxes.size()) {
            System.out.println("The puzzle is full!" + "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    System.out.print(puzzle[i][j]);                 
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + "The filler method was run " + runs + " times");
            return;
        }

        //Assuming the puzzle isn't full, find the row/column of the blankBoxes index.
        int row = blankBoxes.get(currentIndex) / 10;
        int column = blankBoxes.get(currentIndex) % 10;
        //Adds one to the value of that box.
        puzzle[row][column] =  (puzzle[row][column] + 1);

        //Just used as a breakpoint for a debugger.
        if(row == 4 && column == 4){
            int x  = 0;
        }

        //If the value is 10, meaning it went through all the possible values:
        if(puzzle[row][column] == 10) {
            //Do filler() on the previous box
            puzzle[row][column] = 0;
            currentIndex--;
            filler(currentIndex);
        }
        //If the number is 1-9, but there are duplicates:
        else if(!(checkSingleRow(row) && checkSingleColumn(column) && checkSingleBox(row, column))) {
            //Do filler() on the same box.
            filler(currentIndex);
        }
        //If the number is 1-9, and there is no duplicate:
        else {
            currentIndex++;
            filler(currentIndex);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Used to check if a single row has any duplicates or not. This is called by the 
     * filler method.
     * @param row
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean checkSingleRow(int row) {
        return checkDupl(puzzle[row]);
    }

    /**
     * Used to check if a single column has any duplicates or not. 
     * filler method, as well as the checkColumns of the checker.
     * @param column
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean checkSingleColumn(int column) {
        int[] singleColumn = new int[9];
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            singleColumn[i] = puzzle[i][column];
        }
        return checkDupl(singleColumn);         
    }

    public static boolean checkSingleBox(int row, int column) {
        //Makes row and column be the first row and the first column of the box in which
        //this specific cell appears. So, for example, the box at puzzle[3][7] will iterate
        //through a box from rows 3-6 and columns 6-9 (exclusive).
        row = (row / 3) * 3;
        column = (column / 3) * 3;

        //Iterates through the box
        int[] newBox = new int[9];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = row; i < row + 3; i++) {
            for(int j = row; j < row + 3; j++) {
                newBox[counter] = puzzle[i][j];
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return checkDupl(newBox);
    }
}
```

Why am I calling it a weird error? A few reasons:

1. The box that the error occurs on changes randomly (give or take a box).
2. The actual line of code that the error occurs on changes randomly (it seems to usually happen in the filler method, but that's probably just because that's the biggest one.
3. Different compilers have different errors in different boxes (probably related to 1)

What I assume is that I just wrote inefficient code, so though it's not an actual infinite recursion, it's bad enough to call a Stack Overflow Error. But if anyone that sees a glaring issue, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Which method is throwing `StackOverFlow` Error?

Comment: @Mac Usually in the main filler method, but it's scattered around, because the filler method is calling all the other ones. Sometimes it's in the checkSingleRow, sometimes in the checkDupl...really everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not backtracking. Backtracking implies return back on failure:

```
 if(puzzle[row][column] == 10) {
        puzzle[row][column] = 0;
        currentIndex--;
        filler(currentIndex);// but every fail you go deeper
    }
```

There are must be something like:

```
public boolean backtrack(int currentIndex) {
    if (NoBlankBoxes())
        return true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) {
        if (NoDuplicates()) {
            puzzle[row][column] = i;
            ++currentIndex;
            if (backtrack(currentIndex) == true) {
                return true;
            }
            puzzle[row][column] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but every fail you go deeper"? If the value for the box is 10, that means that it went through all the values of 1-9, and is now attempting the next value (10), which means that there's no possible value for that box. Thus, I set it to 0, subtract one from the index, and run filler on the new index, which is the previous empty box.                                            Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there no possible values for that box, you take previous empty box and again call "filler", instead of return from this recursion step. Thus after some small time you get StackOverflow.

Comment: I added my own modification to address this issue, and it's now working perfectly. Thanks for the help!